# REST API url and parameter naming with in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, api, rest

For Spring Boot projects, I have seen some different usages and want to clarify the following points.

**1-** As far as I know, the following usage in the url with kebab-case is better than camelCase. Is it true?

```
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/fraud-check")
```

**2-** On the other hand, if we use parameter, then I think it is better to us camelCase in the url as shown below (attention that I use camelCase only for parameters, the rest (`security-check`) is kebab-case). Is this  a proper usage?

```
@GetMapping("/security-check/{customerId}/{jobId}")
public ResponseEntity<List<Customer>> getCustomerByDepartmentIdAndJobId(
                                          @PathVariable int customerId,
                                          @PathVariable int jobId
) {

}
```

On the other hand, there are some cases when both parameter are the same type e.g. `getById()` and `getByReferenceNumber()`. In this case the following url mappings cannot be used:

```
@GetMapping("/{userId}")
```

and

```
@GetMapping("/{referenceId}")
```

In this case, is it a good practice to add an extra parameter ('references') to reference one as shown below:

```
@GetMapping("/references/{referenceId}")
```

What would you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your point regarding casing is completely valid and it goes well with how APIs are written generally.

We have a great article that will help you get started with what are the best practices for REST apis:
https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/02/best-practices-for-rest-api-design/

At the end regarding your end use case of endpoint:

```
@GetMapping("/references/{referenceId}")
```

This is really subjective and will depend on your use case.
For instance, adding "references" will also depend on your class-level requestmapping string which speaks about what is the domain of the controller class.

Suppose I have Controller specifically written for Reference I can go like:

```
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/reference")
@Controller
class ReferenceController {

@GetMapping("/{id}")
... getReferenceById (@PathVariable int id) {}
}
```

Hope this clarifies the point and helps. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, it sounds very useful. Regarding to the last part of my question, I am asking that. For example I have 2 endpoints who get customer by id and iban. Then, the endpoints urls are ambiguous. For this reason I should change at least one of them. So, for this scenario, should I change only one of them as `@GetMapping("/ibans/{id}")` or change both of them (for id one use `@GetMapping("ids/{id}")`)? Any idea?

Comment: do you have an idea about my last comment?

Comment: Hi, @jonathan let me understand. so as you are saying iban and id both give you a customer object lets suppose in response. so you want to know which one should you be keeping?

Comment: I want to keep both of them because I want to get them by id or by iban via 2 different endpoints.

Comment: 100% you can do that. but keep that in mind then those endpoints might be part of different Controllers ok? Being said that as both the endpoints are fetching the same data. it will be great to have a single endpoint to remove duplicate code. But again very subjective to your need/app.

Comment: I use both of them in the same controller. On the other hand, if I have a single endpoint to get record via id or iban, then I will have to use if block that is also not good. For this purpose, ı think this way is better to follow single responsibility. What do you think?

Comment: That is correct. in fact, that will be a cumbersome api to work with. think about it now your result will depend upon what your condition resolves to, scary isn't it? I think a better way will be writing like @GetMapping("user/{Id}") getUserById & @GetMapping("user/{refId}") getUserByRefenceId. lastly, the single responsibility concept is more to do with the design of classes rather than our logic mostly. but yea to keep your code modular and cleaner better not to have branches to a single endpoint.